# Balanced paranthesis in graph

Tags: java

I have a graph in the form of the one in the picture and I want to obtain a String expression with parenthesis. [image: graph]
I have implemented the recursive DFS, but I cannot wrap my head around the ways to balance the parenthesis.

```
public void recursiveDFS(NodeGraph node){
    System.out.print(node + " ");
    List<NodeGraph> children = node.getChildren();
    node.setVisited(true);
    for (int currentIndex = 0; currentIndex < children.size(); currentIndex++) {
        NodeGraph currentNode = children.get(currentIndex);
        if (currentNode != null && currentNode.getIsVisited() == false) {
            recursiveDFS(currentNode);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include the NodeGraph class itself in the question and convert the image to some ASCII art - it is generally frowned on to link images. The data graph in the image shows the root containing data but having a child.  All other data nodes are leaf nodes whereas all the remaining logical nodes are within the tree.  The shown expression does not include the root node.  The logical nodes are shown with no more than 2 sub-nodes but the sample code you provided indicates that there is a List of child Nodes - this implies you may have more than two children, true?

Answer (score 1):

You should probably differentiate between leaf nodes (like yy9, yy5, yy21 and yy27) and non leaf nodes (like and, or).

Non-leaf nodes with more than 1 child should be wrapped in parenthesis.
That should do the trick.